# Using Powershell to find only those global holidays that occur today

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I'm new to using Powershell and I'm trying to scrape a website to find ONLY those global holidays occurring today, using the website below.

https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/global/holidayCalendar.jhtml

Here is what I've got so far, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$a = Get-Date -UFormat "%m/%d/%y" #to get the date in mm/dd/yy format
$source = "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/global/holidayCalendar.jhtml"
$result = Invoke-WebRequest $source
$d = $result.AllElements | Where Class -eq "layout-calendar-content-column" | Select -ExpandProperty innerText 

echo $d
```

Ideally, it would only show those holidays that match the date contained in the variable $a.

Comment: What is your current output from `$d`?

Comment: This [post by Lee Holmes](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2015/01/05/extracting-tables-from-powershells-invoke-webrequest/) would be helpful. Turn the tables into PowerShell objects, then you can filter using `Where-Object` only for the specified day.

Comment: All countries, all dates, all holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is almost complete.  Instead of your `echo` statement, try this:

```
$d -split "`n" | ? { $_ -like "*$a*" }
```

---

Update: For your use-case

```
($d | Out-String) -split "`n" | Where-Object { $_ -like "*$a*" }
```

Comment: If I get rid of the echo statement, then it doesn't output anything at all. Or would do I do the echo $d, after your statement?

Comment: It should output.. How are you running the script? @Ryan

Comment: I just put the entire script into the editor and hit F5 to run it.

Comment: @Ryan Try appending `| Out-Host` to the pipeline.

Comment: I tried:

$d -split "`n" | ? { $_ -like "*$a*" } | Out-Host

And still nothing.

Comment: I think it's a version issue. I am using Powershell 3 at work, but Powershell 5 at home. I tried this at home and it worked, but at the office, it did not. Oh well.

Comment: @Ryan What's the type reported by `$d.GetType().FullName`?  It's a string, right?

Comment: The command: $d.GetType().FullName returns:   

System.Object[]

Comment: Based on your comment that the data type should be a string (good observation by the way!), I added | Out-String to the pipeline to transform $d to a string. And now $d.GetType().FullName returns System.String. But still not getting anywhere.